# How do I import __future__ in org-mode babel

Tags: org-mode, python, org-babel

Attempting to eval a babel source block that contains a `__future__` import and also uses a `:var` causes Python to spit out

```
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: from __future__ imports must occur at the beginning of the file
```

Presumably babel is sticking the `:var` definitions before the first line of my code. How can I prevent babel from doing this?

Minimum failing example:

```
#+NAME: data
| Hi | 2 |

#+BEGIN_SRC python :var data=data
  from __future__ import print_function
  print(*data)
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `prologue` header argument.  Like this:

```
#+NAME: data
| Hi  | 2 |
| Bye | 3 |

#+name: test-py27-with-print-function
#+header: :prologue "from __future__ import print_function"
#+BEGIN_SRC python :var data=data :results output list
  for row in data:
      print(*row)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-py27-with-print-function
: - Hi 2
: - Bye 3
```